# Solow Model in disrectly and continuously

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, mathematical-economics, economic-growth, solow

what is the differences between solow model in disrectly time and continuously time?
Why in disrectly time function use the equation: k(t+1)=(1-δ)k(t) + sf(k(t)) and in continuously time function use: dy/dt = s*f(k) - δk. Are they different? (i think they are not)

Answer (score 3):

The discrete time law of motion is given by
$k(t+1) = (1-\delta)k(t) + s f(k(t))$
This can be rewritten as:
$$
(k(t+1)-k(t)) = s f(k(t)) - \delta k(t).
$$
Now, take a Taylor expansion of order 1 of $k(t+1)$ around $t$.
$$
k(t+1) \approx k(t) + \frac{\partial k}{\partial t}(t),\\
\to k(t+1) - k(t) \approx \frac{\partial k}{\partial t}(t).
$$
This gives:
$$
\frac{\partial k}{\partial t}(t) = sf(k(t)) - \delta k(t)
$$

So we are basically exchanging the discrete difference $\Delta k(t) = k(t+1) - k(t)$ by its continuous approximation $\dfrac{\partial k}{\partial t}(t)$.

Comment: I wonder why at the beginning (()) is steeper than (), but at some point, it starts flatter than ()?